# DynamicComponent only works when method is in same component as DynamicComponent

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

My problem is following:

I need to display content dynamically according to a method from a different component than the
the DynamicComponent tag is in.

Is this by design or did I do sth wrong?

My code:

Platform.razor:

```
<a href="" @onclick:preventDefault @onclick="@(()=>ChangePage("ListLinks"))>
```

```
public Type? selectedPage = typeof(Empty);
    public void ChangePage(string page)
    {
        selectedPage = page.Length > 0 ? Type.GetType($"Namespace.Shared.{page}") : null;
    }
```

Home.razor:

`Platform platform = new Platform();`

`<DynamicComponent Type="@platform.selectedPage"></DynamicComponent>`

When I call the method inside the same component, everything works but it's not what I need.

Comment: I do think your `Type?  selectedPage` is a parameter? Parameter's don't bubble up if they get updated. That said, your Home.razor will not see the change. You might need an event for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
Platform platform = new Platform();
```

creates a new instance of `Platform` which is unconnected with the instance created by the Renderer.  You do not manage component instances.

To communicate between components you can use a DI service.

Here's some code that demonstrates something like what you want to do:

First a service:

```cs
public class PlatformService
{
    public Type? Component { get; private set; }
    public event EventHandler? ComponentChanged;
    
    public void SetComponent(Type type)
    {
        this.Component= type;
        this.ComponentChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Registered in `Program` as scoped so it persists for the lifetime of the user SPA instance.

```cs
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<PlatformService>();
```

A component to change the component type:

```cs
@inject PlatformService service
<h3>ComponentSelector</h3>

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => Change(typeof(Counter))"> Counter </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => Change(typeof(FetchData))"> FetchData </button>
</div>

@code {
    private void Change(Type type)
        => service.SetComponent(type);
}
```

And Index to demo it.  Note it implements an event handler registered on the service event to drive the UI update.

```cs
@page "/"
@inject PlatformService service
@implements IDisposable
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<ComponentSelector />

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@if (service.Component is not null)
{
    <DynamicComponent Type="service.Component" />
}

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => this.service.ComponentChanged += this.OnUpdated;

    private void OnUpdated(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        => this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

    public void Dispose()
        => this.service.ComponentChanged -= this.OnUpdated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, if you have the method inside the same component it works, and as soon as you put it to the child level, it doesn't. And that is by design.

Let's assume you have the following structure:
Parent.razor

```
<h1>@Text</h1>
<Child Text="@text">/
@code {
    private string Text = "Hello World";
}
```

And you update `text` inside your child, the parent component will **not** see the change:

Child.razor

```
<button @onclick="() =>Text = string.Empty">Click Me</button>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public string Text { get; set; }= "";
}
```

So clicking on "Click Me" will not change the header in your parent component. The same applies to your example.

Now, how do we make this work? The most straightforward approach would be to have an event, fired when your dynamic component changes, on which the parent component listens. For that, you can also use a event (this special form is a two-way-binding: https://blazor-university.com/components/two-way-binding/)

```cs
[Parameter]
public Type SelectedPage { get; set; } = typeof(Empty);

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<Type> SelectedPageChanged { get; set; }

public async Task ChangePage(string page)
{
    selectedPage = page.Length > 0 ? Type.GetType($"Namespace.Shared.{page}") : null;
    await SelectedPageChanged.InvokeAsync(selectedPage);
}
```

I am not sure if the following will work with `DynamicComponent`s.

```
<DynamicComponent @bind-Type="@platform.selectedPage"></DynamicComponent>
```

If that doesn't work you can fallback to this:

Platform.razor

```
<DynamicComponent Type="@platform.SelectedPage" Parameters="@dynamicParameters"/>

@code {
    private Dictionary<string, object> dynamicComponentParameters = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
         dynamicComponentParameters.Add("SelectedPageChanged", EventCallback.Factory.Create<Type>(this, SelectedTypeChanged));

    }

    private void SelectedTypeChanged(Type newType)
    {
        // After the method a re-render will be triggered
        platForm.SelectedPage = newType;
    }
}
```